# keep getting empty result on my previous promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

```
    this.state = {
      city: null,
      cityNumber : null,
      typeWeather: "",
      minTemp: 0,
      maxTemp: 0,
      theTemp: 0
    };
  }


  SearchingCity = (city) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=${city}`)
      .then((result) => {
        let cityName = result.data[0].woeid;
            this.setState({
              city: cityName
            });
            resolve(cityName)
      })
    })
  }

  getCityID = async () => {
    const cityID = await this.SearchingCity();
    console.log(cityID)
    this.setState({
      cityNumber : cityID
    })
    const thisID = this.state.cityNumber;
    axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${thisID}`)
    .then((result) => {
      const type_Weather = result.data.consolidated_weather[0].weather_state_name
      const min_Temp = result.data.consolidated_weather[0].min_temp
      const max_Temp = result.data.consolidated_weather[0].max_temp
      const the_Temp = result.data.consolidated_weather[0].the_temp

      this.setState({
        typeWeather : type_Weather,
        minTemp : min_Temp,
        maxTemp : max_Temp,
        theTemp : the_Temp
      })
    })
  }
```

so in the console.log(cityID) it's supposed to be the result from *SearchingCity* method, but
when i console.log(cityID), i got the empty result, where is the part i should change?

thank you guys

Comment: probably because you are not passing any city to the method?  `const cityID = await this.SearchingCity(CITY_YOU_WANT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as  **@gbalduzzi** pointerd out,
The Problem is here,

```
const cityID = await this.SearchingCity();
//                                     ^^
```

Your not calling `SearchingCity` with any `city` parameter as needed in,

```
  SearchingCity = (city) => {
//                ^^^^^^
```